# PSCP - why can't it find the file when using non-admin credentials?

Tags: scp, file-copy, sftp, putty, pscp

I am trying to make a batch script to get files from Windows vm to Ubuntu vm so I decided to use pscp.

when I put `pscp -l admin -pw pswd C:\path admin@IP:/path` the files transfer fine but I don't want to transfer as admin for security reasons. 
So when I use `pscp -l user -pw pswd2 C:\path user@IP:/path` it says "The system cannot find the file specified"

I am very confused. When I ssh as user I can find the directory specified, also it doesn't seem like an access problem because user owns the folder and I changed it so that anyone can write to it. Does anyone know why it's doing this?

Comment: `C\:path`?  That looks wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo C:\ -- but my actual command is correct/the same for the 2 users so thats not the problem :(

Comment: does `user` have permissions to read through all of the parent directories to the destination `/path`?

Comment: Yupp!  It owns all the directories except home, but it has permission to read it